# How can I remove the outer area of ​a circle with opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv

I need to remove the outer area of ​​the circle.

I need to use only the inner area of ​​the circle to avoid errors in image processing, currently I can only find the circle and mark it

I do not know if I'm doing it right, using cv2.circle

Please help me

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(cinza, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20)

if circles is not None:
    maior = 0
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

    for i in circles[0, :]:
         radius = i[2]
         if radius > maior:
            maior = radius

    for i in circles[0, :]:
        center = (i[0], i[1])
        radius = i[2]
        if radius == maior:
            cv2.circle(image, center, 1, (0, 100, 100), 3)
            cv2.circle(image, center, radius, (255, 0, 255), 3)
```

Comment: Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fdKL.png)?

Answer (score 2):

First use [numpy meshgrid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) to get a matrix for x and y with the indices of the image. Then calculate the distance of the indices to the center of your circle by subtracting the centroid from the indice matrices, for x and y each.

Afterwards calculate the distances of the pixels to the centroid using

```
distances = (x**2 + y**2)**0.5
```

`x`, `y`, `image` and `distances` must have the same shape now.

Then use [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html) on the distances matrix to pick the pixels within the circle and set them e.g. to zero like

```
image[distances > 0.5] = 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mask](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=opencv%20mask%20area&rlz=1C1GGRV_enTR783TR783&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq4Yj4jrzZAhVLDcAKHSRrDSQQ_AUICigB&biw=1280&bih=928) functions of OpenCV. In this link, you can see mask functions on c++, I could not find Python function on official pages but [there](https://github.com/ArunJayan/OpenCV-Python/blob/master/masking.py) is a code for masking by OpenCV on Python.

As a summary, you can mask outer size of a circle by OpenCV mask functions to remove outer area of the circle.